# NullPointerException reference SharedPrefence java.lang.String, int

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have shared the data collected with Firebase Crashlytics below. Many users crash because of this. How can I solve this problem?

Regards.

```java
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
       at com.myproject.utils.PreferencesUtils.setAdmobEnable(PreferencesUtils.java:3)
       at com.myproject.ui.MainActivity$9.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:220)
```

BaseActivity class:

```java
protected Context mContext;
```

PreferencesUtils class:

```java
public static boolean getAdMobEnable(final Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
        Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE, 0
    );
    return preferences.getBoolean(Constants.ADMOB_ENABLE, true);
}
    
public static void setAdmobEnable(final Context context, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
        Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE, 0
    );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(Constants.ADMOB_ENABLE, value);
    editor.apply();
}
```

I am using the code below

```java
PreferencesUtils.setAdmobEnable(mContext, true);
```

or

```java
if (user.membership == null || user.membership != 1) {
    //user.membership is an Integer data and this data is downloaded with Firebase realtime database.
    PreferencesUtils.setAdmobEnable(mContext, true);
} else {
    PreferencesUtils.setAdmobEnable(mContext, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `Context#getSharedPreferences` on a non-defined variable.

You should define your `Context mContext` or instantiate your class with your framework in case you are using one. Frameworks or libraries can't do his magic if you don't follow their requirements.

Comment: So what should I do? Context context via MainActivity instead of BaseActivity; should i create?

Comment: @howtci Set `mContext = this` in your `onCreate()` method.